# jQuery scroll to anchor with exception

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, anchor

friends,

I'm building single page website, which uses the jQuery function to scroll to an anchor, when the menu link is being selected. Here is the code I use:

```
(function($) {
    var jump = function(e)
    {
        if (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var target = $(this).attr("href");
        } else {
            var target = location.hash;
        }
        $('html,body').animate(
        {
            scrollTop: $(target).offset().top - 150
        }, 1500, 'swing', function()
        {
            location.hash = target - 150;
        });
    }
    $('html, body').hide()
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('a[href^=#]').bind("click", jump);
        if (location.hash) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('html, body').scrollTop(0).show()
                jump()
            }, 0);
        } else {
            $('html, body').show()
        }
    });
})(jQuery)
```

Now this function is called for all html 'a' elements with 'href'. I need to modify the function above, so it would work for all defined links except this one with the anchor `#nav-menu`:

```
 <a href="#nav-menu" id="toggle"><span></span></a>
```

Any suggestions would be very appreciated.

Comment: `$('a[href^=#]:not(#toggle)').bind("click", jump);`, Also use `.on()`

Comment: @Satpal I'm not sure what you had in mind by saying "also use `.on()`". However, the first part of your comment fixed my problem. Thank you.

Comment: As `.bind()` is deprecated in the favor of [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/), So _also use `.on()`_ is intended to recommend the usage on the method `.on()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jquery provide a set of built-in filters that you can use in your case you may use:

- the built in filter not() as following:-

  ```
  $("a[href^=#]:not([href=#nav-menu])").click(jump);
  ```
- build you own business filter as following:-

  ```
  $("a[href^=#]").filter(function() {
      //you may here do whatever filteration business you want
      return $(this).attr("href")!='#nav-menu';
  }).click(jump);
  ```

Simple Example [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/elshenawy000/gtehwped/3/)